# Hardware buttons handling in android while deep sleep

Tags: android, button, event-handling

So my main problem :
Cant start mp3 playback if the phone goes sleep for a few min.
When the phone goes sleep for a few min there is 90% chance none of the hardware button works but the power button.
Cant understand why is the power button working always and the others only 10%. When i clicking mad for  5sec it usually registers. 
Buttons working well if the phone is awake.

```
blade_keypad.kl
key 158   BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
key 139   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
key 102   HOME              WAKE

key 115   VOLUME_UP         WAKE
key 114   VOLUME_DOWN       WAKE
key 116   POWER             WAKE
key 142   POWER             WAKE

key 226   HEADSETHOOK   WAKE
```

Not sure if it is a kernel or android issue.
Using a ZTE Blade cm-10.1-20130724-KonstaKANG-blade .
How can i test pressed button while in deep sleep? Was thinking maybe u can enable debugging options so it adds keypress to locgat. But how?
So if that works then its an android bug. Witch program broadcast the key-press events to the others? I have to take a look at that.
Probably buttons do not wake up the phone but why does power button wake it up? Why is that different?

Edit: 
okay I did some reading ... There is nothing running while deep sleep cause the processor totally stopped. Area the hardware buttons wakening up the cpu buy a hardware irq? Or it just querying it ? Maybe just the power button have an irq the other button are queried ?

Comment: @CommonsWare can u take a look at my question pls ? :D thx :P

Comment: Update:I can start the audio from deep sleep by holding the headset button for 6 sec release and click. Back Menu and Home does not wake up the phone this way... Any theories whats going on?

Comment: Update 2: changed key 226   MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE WAKE now it works. Without WAKE it worked but power button dint not worked from deep sleep. Strange. Maybe the lock screen app east the HEADSETHOOK events. Any ideas?

Comment: Update 3: Crap there was a "taos" kernel wakelock keeping the phone awake the whole time so the MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE does not work :S

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with my xperia s stock 4.0.3. Tried to find solution, but no luck :(. So I've searched all *.kl files in system/usr/keylayout folder for "HEADSETHOOK" keyword, and finally fix that issue by adding "WAKE" to "key 226 HEADSETHOOK" in Generic.kl, so it became "key 226   HEADSETHOOK WAKE". After that I hate my phone much less :))

Comment: Well I did  try to comment out the buttons in blade_keypad.kl and write the WAKE in Generic.kl the result was none of the buttons waked up the phone not even the power button :P . The MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE change works if I press long the the button. But now I cant pick up the phone with the headset button.